# PDO and MySQL 'max_user_connections'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP REST API for Android, Windows Phone and iOS apps. The API's response is always a JSON. We're using a DataBase class to manage the PDO connection and the CRUD operations. Sometimes we had the following error `Message: SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User my_user already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections`.

I found some instructions that recommended to set the PDO object variable to null, something like `$pdo = null` or `unset($pdo)`. So, I've created a destructor method in my DataBase class to unset my PDO instance:

```
public function __destruct(){
    $this->pdo = null;
    unset($this->pdo);
}
```

But sometimes I got the error again. Could someone help me?

Comment: Do you destroy these instances as soon as possible ? (Sounds obvious but still) Maybe you could share a code sample where the problem occurs.

Comment: I destroy the PDO instance just inside the DataBase's `__destruct()` method. Is it enough?

Comment: It depends when you call the destructor of course, that's why I asked for a code sample. If you call it at the very end of your script, 20 seconds after your last use of your DB, it's pointless.

Comment: You gave me some light, thanks Clément. I have a singleton class API that instantiates the DataBase class. I'm not killing the API class nor the DataBase class, so the DataBase's `__destruct()` method never starts. I'll try this and post my result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you use for connections background? Do you use connection pooling?

Look PHP documentation topic "[Connections and Connection management](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)"

> **Note:**
>
> If you're using the PDO ODBC driver and your ODBC libraries support
>   ODBC Connection Pooling (unixODBC and Windows are two that do; there
>   may be more), then it's recommended that you don't use persistent PDO
>   connections, and instead leave the connection caching to the ODBC
>   Connection Pooling layer. The ODBC Connection Pool is shared with
>   other modules in the process; if PDO is told to cache the connection,
>   then that connection would never be returned to the ODBC connection
>   pool, resulting in additional connections being created to service
>   those other modules.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I removed `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE` from my code and added the `__destruct()` methods to unset my DataBase and PDO. Now, when I try `SHOW PROCESSLIST` on MySQL I don't have idle connections anymore.